# linking databases in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a NSF , in that "new request" one action button is there, when am clicking that one, first it is throwing an error like "Master database cannot found please contact "NSF name" administrator" and it will opening the corresponding page.

Here my question is

Is that database is linkup with another( may be that's why it is throwing the error), if so then how can i link up the master database with the actual database to avoid that error

please help..thank you very much

Comment: So you're saying the error occurs but the application still operates as expected?

Comment: Click on the "status" bar at the bottom of your Notes client after the error occurs. Are there any messages there to tell you more about the problem? Maybe the location of the database it was trying to open

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. You should post the code from the "New Request" action.

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a missing configuration document that identifies to the master database. The person who wrote the code actually wrote a good error trapping routine because it tells you what happened. However, without seeing the code, we can't tell you how to fix the problem.

There is no specific "linkage" between Notes databases. The developer wrote custom code to interact with that other database and there's no way to know how without seeing that code.

Answer (score 0):

Action buttons that access other Notes databases typically use the filepath and server name or sometimes the target database replicaID, if these are hardcoded in the new request action button (very bad programming, but not uncommon in old applications) and the target database has been moved, or renamed or more likely a copy has been made with a new replicaID then the button will fail.

The path to the target database may also be stored in a configuration document which hasn't been updated when one of the above happened. These will usually only be accessible to database administrators and hidden unless you have manager or manager level access to the database. You will need to get the Lotus Notes adminis involved but look at the code so you can tell them what they are looking for.